# Can't get in to dark brotherhood

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have completed the quest where you help the boy in Windhelm by killing the woman in the orphange and returned the quest, but I have not gotten the note and therefore cannot start the dark brotherhood questline.
Are there some other prerequisites in which case which?
And if it is just a bug, is there any console command that might help?

Comment: The note is optional, and is just to give you a hint that the Dark Brotherhood is watching you. Just go to sleep and a Dark Brotherhood Party Associate will escort you to your cake.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You should add that as an answer

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I have tried sleeping, still doesn't work

Comment: Have you returned to Windhelm and handed in the quest?

Comment: You need to wait for the note. Make sure your couriers haven't died.

Answer (score 5):

Simply find a bed and go to sleep. Sleep for around 10 hours and when you wake up "I don't want to spoil it"

Comment: I have slept but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to manually mark your stage as completed by using the following command:

'SetObjectiveCompleted   <1 to set, 0 to unset>'

I found the quest ID and stage for you, so simply type this into the console:

`SetObjectiveCompleted DB01 200 1`

This will force-complete the quest. Then sleep in a bed for 24 hours (just to be safe). You should move on to the next quest.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Could you please tell me what quest is active currently? A screenshot of your objectives will be useful. Post it in the Root Access room (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your house or an inn, and sleep for 24 hours. Then, the magic happens.